# Confused on DocumentListener and printing to textarea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

Im not sure what goes where. Im using a GUI `Jframe` `textarea`.

I want to print into the textarea a changing `int` based on player score.

If you need elaboration please let me know.

```
private void scoreComponentAdded(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    score.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
    printIt(Jscore);
}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
    printIt(documentEvent);
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
    printIt(documentEvent);
}

private void printIt(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
    DocumentEvent.EventType type = documentEvent.getType();
    //your code
}

        private void printIt(int Jscore) {
            printIt(Jscore);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: honestly, is this homework? what have you tried already?

Comment: @desperateCoder Yes its for a class, im doing GUI which has not been taught, this is a last bit i need for my program to work, have I tried?, well I looked at some examples but none of them told me "where" to put the code, and with 900+ lines of code its a little hard to "try".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code, where the comment tells you to:

```
private void printIt(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
    DocumentEvent.EventType type = documentEvent.getType();
    //your code
}
```

What code you have to put in, depends on the environment of your code.
Typically, you have to get the new value, maybe from the `documentEvent`, and then set the Text into your `TextArea` by calling the `setText()` method on it.

Comment: Is it supposed to be written like this? String `Thescore = Integer.toString(Jscore);
    score.setText(Thescore);`

Comment: @Magiichalo looks good, doesn't it work? you should write the variable names lower case, btw

Comment: It looks like it should, but its not printing anything. Thanks for reply, ill do some more testing.

Comment: try to debug through your code by setting breakpoints, this helps a lot.

Comment: Actually, i placed the code in `public JeopardyGUI() {
        initComponents();
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        
        String thescore = Integer.toString(jscore);
        score.setText(thescore); 
        System.out.print(thescore);
    }` and I displays 0 and prints 0. But the item thats supposed to trigger the value to change is in a `private void` and It doesnt allow me to change it to public (Thanks for your help btw)

Comment: youre welcome! in this case, what type is jscore of? if i'm not mistaken, you are looking for the event source? you can get it by calling  `documentEvent.getDocument()`

Comment: Thanks so much, i figured it out.

Comment: My pleasure, i'm glad, that i could help!